# How does a static Dictionary have cyclomatic complexity?

Tags: c#-4.0, cyclomatic-complexity

I have the following class:

```
public static class MyClass
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> valueTypes;

    static MyClass()
    {
        var dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>();
        dictionary.Add(typeof(bool), x => bool.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(byte), x => byte.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(char), x => char.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(decimal), x => decimal.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(double), x => double.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(float), x => float.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(int), x => int.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(long), x => long.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(sbyte), x => sbyte.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(short), x => short.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(uint), x => uint.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(ulong), x => ulong.Parse(x));
        dictionary.Add(typeof(ushort), x => ushort.Parse(x));
        MyClass.valueTypes = dictionary;
    }
}
```

However, Microsoft Code Analysis flags this as having a cyclomatic complexity of 27. I do not understand why a series of Add calls with delegates results in such a high cyclomatic complexity.

What can I do to reduce the cyclomatic complexity?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244131/how-can-the-cyclomatic-complexity-be-27-in-a-method-with-13-event-handler-subscr

Comment: Lambda expressions are like an iceberg.  The syntax sugar is very sweet but this code creates 13 nested classes and 26 conditional branches in the constructor code.  The only way to see it is to look at it the way the analysis tool does, run ildasm.exe on the assembly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I like this definition for CC - `the amount of decision logic in a source code function` (See more on "[Code Metrics – Cyclomatic Complexity](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/zainnab/archive/2011/05/17/code-metrics-cyclomatic-complexity.aspx)", there is also very good example how is CC calculated).

So since each `Add()` has two different code paths - `Add()` itself and `Value` function, so `CC+=2`. Since you put `Add()` 13 times - `CC ==` at least `26`. And regarding MSDN minimal CC is `2` and when it increased it start increasing from 1, so you ends up with 27 :) Having an anonymous method in a dictionary value increases a complexity since potentially it may raise an exception so should be covered by a test as well.

[Code Metrics Values, MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385914.aspx):

> Cyclomatic Complexity – Measures the structural complexity of the
>   code. It is created by calculating the number of different code paths
>   in the flow of the program. A program that has complex control flow
>   will require more tests to achieve good code coverage and will be less
>   maintainable.

---

Just of interest check what are CC for these examples:

```
private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>> valueTypes
static MyClass()     
{         
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>();         
    dictionary.Add(typeof(bool), x => bool.Parse(x)); 
}


static MyClass()     
{         
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>();         
    Func<string, object> func = (x) => bool.Parse(x)
    dictionary.Add(typeof(bool), func); 
}

static MyClass()     
{         
    var dictionary = new Dictionary<Type, Func<string, object>>();         
    dictionary.Add(typeof(bool), null); 
}
```